# Did North Korea say "we will meet you on the nuclear battlefield", causing Trump to cancel June 12 summit?

Tags: united-states, north-korea

On CNN (5/27/18) Rudy Giuliani said that North Korea's statement on May 23 (that Trump characterized as "tremendous anger and open hostility displayed in your most recent statement") contained the statement that DPRK would meet the US on the nuclear battlefield.

I cannot find any such May statement, can anyone else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [CNN,](https://www.cnn.com/2018/05/23/politics/mike-pence-north-korea-intl/index.html) on Thursday, May 24, 2018:

> **"Whether the US will meet us at a meeting room or encounter us at nuclear-to-nuclear showdown is entirely dependent upon the decision and behavior of the United States,"** Choe said in comments carried by North Korea's state-run KCNA news agency Thursday.

Choe Son-Hui is a vice-minister in the North Korean Foreign Ministry.  Her comments were in response to those of Vice-President Mike Pence a few days prior:

> Choe was responding to comments by Pence made Monday during a Fox News interview that she deemed "unbridled and impudent." ...
>
> "There was some talk about the Libya model," Pence told Fox News' Martha MacCallum. "As the President made clear, this will only end like the Libya model ended if Kim Jong Un doesn't make a deal."
>
> When MacCallum said that some people may have seen Bolton's comments as a threat, Pence said "I think it's more of a fact."

Comment: Thanks, Choe Son-Hui's statement (while probably "angry") doesn't appear to be particularly hostile, more of a statement of fact (a nuclear showdown **is** dependent on US behavior).  Giulani's characterization mischaracterized her statement.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that it is a direct quote, but North Korea [did](https://edition.cnn.com/2018/05/23/politics/mike-pence-north-korea-intl/index.html) say this:

> "Whether the US will meet us at a meeting room or encounter us at nuclear-to-nuclear showdown is entirely dependent upon the decision and behavior of the United States," [vice-minister in the North Korean Foreign Ministry] Choe said in comments carried by North Korea's state-run KCNA news agency Thursday.

There is [also](https://www.vox.com/world/2018/5/24/17380092/trump-north-korea-kim-jong-un-summit-meeting-canceled) a more threatening quote (it doesn't directly refer to nuclear attacks though):

> Trump is likely referring to a Wednesday statement by North Korean Vice Foreign Minister Choe Son Hui in which she warned that North Korea “can also make the U.S. taste an appalling tragedy it has neither experienced nor even imagined up to now,” according to the state-run Korean Central News Agency.

Various news sites attribute the interview to either Wednesday or Thursday. My guess is that the confusion stems from the time difference.